# Как найти текст в БД SQL lite по предложению Python

Tags: python, алгоритм, sqlite

Есть база данных с текстами. Задача найти текст песни по отрывку. Подскажите алгоритм для поиска.

Comment: Смотрите в сторону полнотекстового поиска и использования внешних поисковых движков.

Answer (score 0):

Вы бы указали хотя бы названия таблиц и полей в них, пример кода, который Вы пытались сделать... Подсказать может без проблем учебник или видео, а делать за Вас - это уже другое.
В любом случае:

```
import sqlite3

with sqlite3.connect("name_database.db", check_same_thread=False) as adb:
    cur = adb.cursor()
    cur.execute(f"""SELECT имя_столбка 
    FROM название_таблицы 
    WHERE имя_столбца 
    LIKE '%текст вашей песни или {variable}, которая его содержит%'
    """)
    result = cur.fetchall()
    print(result)
```